# delete data from mysql table based on multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, python-2.7

i need to delete rows from MySQL table which is very huge.I have multiple conditions check before deleting the data.
my table looks like: data(table name):

```
   name  mobile email address source
    xyz   871    a@y.com        1.txt
    bac   123     null          2.XLS
    TST   456     B@C.COM       3.xls
    yup   897     null          abcde
    web   null    D@gmail.com   hjbsb
```

so basically i need to delete the rows where value in Source doesnt end with either .TXT or .txt or .xls or .XLS. source is the file-name from which data has been captured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Delete from table_xyz where right(lower(source),4) not in ('.txt','.xls','xlsx')
```

Comment: thanq guys  it was working fine. One more help i didnt understand the code , can u just send  some links to understand

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html - the function right( string , n ) returns the n last chars from string. The functin lower convert chars to lowercase.

Comment: i need to add XLSX and TXT in the query

Comment: i have tried it, but its deleting all rows other than .xls. so am loosing data with rows that have source as .txt or .xlsx

Comment: Maybe there is a space after the suffix?

Comment: there isnt any space, my data looks like 400.xls  369.XLSX   7596.txt. so when am giving  DELETE FROM USER_DATA WHERE RIGHT(SOURCE,4) NOT IN ('.txt','.xls','.xlsx'); except for 400.xls all other are getting deleted. Sorry for the trouble man

Comment: You must delete the dot from xlsx. The right function just returns the 4 last characters.